# Protecting against 'no code' foreach loops in PHP

Tags: php

I'm coming to PHP after years of using C# and can't believe I've just spent hours trying to debug this.   Basically, no matter how many posts I had in my collection, only the last one in the collection was ever updated.

```
foreach($posts as $post); {
    $post->name = 'updated';
    $post->save();
}
```

Of course, the problem was the semi-colon at the end of the foreach, meaning that did nothing, and the block of code I was expecting to run for each item in the array, only ran once after the empty foreach loop had processed.  The code didn't fall over as $post has the value of the last item in the collection.   I'm used to C# protecting me against this sort of stupidity on my part, as $post would only be in scope for the duration of the foreach loop.

My question is therefore, is there a way to protect against this in PHP, so at the very least the code fails at run time with $post either being null or not defined?

Comment: Use the cs fixer / any other analysis tools to check for code violating standards. Use better IDE.

Comment: The [php inspections addon for phpstorm](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7622-php-inspections-ea-extended-) recognizes this as a problem in the phpstorm/intellij. But I know of no way to stop this at either compile time or runtime.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'm using VS Code - have to see if there are any extensions that do a similar thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping in mind that the question asks for a protection at runtime, the short answer is no.

According to the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) there are only 2 types of scopes in PHP: the global scope (so the variable is available everywhere) and a local function scope (the variable is only available inside the function that declares it).

Since your code is valid, you can only get a warning if the `$posts` array has no elements and, because of that, `$post` is undefined. That will trigger just a notice:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: post
```